# Bash First Element in List Recognition

Tags: macos, bash

I'm very new to Bash so I'm sorry if this question is actually very simple. I am dealing with a text file that contains many vertical lists of numbers 2-32 counting up by 2, and each number has a line of other text following it. The problem is that some of the lists are missing numbers. Any pointers for a code that could go through and check to see if each number is there, and if not add a line and put the number in.

One list might look like:

```
2      djhfbadsljfhdsalkfjads;lfkjs
4      dfhadslkfjhasdlkfjhdsalfkjsahf
6      dsa;fghds;lfhsdalfkjhds;fjdsklj
8      daflgkdsakfjhasdlkjhfasdjkhf
12     dlsagflakdjshgflksdhflksdahfl
```

All the way down to 32. How would I in this case make it so the 10 is recognized as missing and then added in above the 12? Thanks!

Comment: What about the extra data in the second column? Would it be empty when you add new?

Comment: Yes, the only thing needed in the new row would be the initial number, the rest of the data would be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one `awk`-based solution (formatted for readability, not necessarily how you would type it):

```
awk '    { value[0 + $1] = $2 }
     END { for (i = 2; i < 34; i+=2)
             print i, value[i]
         }' input.txt
```

It basically just records the existing lines in a key/value pair (associative array), then at the end, prints all the records you care about, along with the (possibly empty) value saved earlier.

Note: if the first column needs to be seen as a string instead of an integer, this variant should work:

```
awk '    { value[$1] = $2 }
     END { for (i = 2; i < 34; i+=2)
             print i, value[i ""]
         }' input.txt
```

Comment: Amazing! Anyway that I could also keep the information trailing after the numbers that do exist?

Comment: My bad. Just noticed I had a stray `$` in there that broke it... Try it again with the `value[i]` instead of `value[$i]`. That should make it do what I said it should...

Comment: That worked for the first value but the rest still don't have the trailing information. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah... confusion between integers and strings. Just added another fix to force the first column to be seen as integers...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to figure out the missing line and add it back:

```
awk '$1==NR*2{i=NR*2+2} i < $1 { while (i<$1) {print i; i+=2} i+=2}
    END{for (; i<=32; i+=2) print i} 1' file
```

**Testing:**

```
cat file
2      djhfbadsljfhdsalkfjads;lfkjs
4      dfhadslkfjhasdlkfjhdsalfkjsahf
6      dsa;fghds;lfhsdalfkjhds;fjdsklj
20     daflgkdsakfjhasdlkjhfasdjkhf
24     dlsagflakdjshgflksdhflksdahfl

awk '$1==NR*2{i=NR*2+2} i < $1 { while (i<$1) {print i; i+=2} i+=2}
    END{for (; i<=32; i+=2) print i} 1' file
2      djhfbadsljfhdsalkfjads;lfkjs
4      dfhadslkfjhasdlkfjhdsalfkjsahf
6      dsa;fghds;lfhsdalfkjhds;fjdsklj
8
10
12
14
16
18
20     daflgkdsakfjhasdlkjhfasdjkhf
22
24     dlsagflakdjshgflksdhflksdahfl
26
28
30
32
```

Comment: -1 This only works right when the missing line is second from last.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this only gives me the last (32) line, not the whole thing.

Comment: What do you mean by `whole thing`? You didn't clarify in your question. Also check updated answer.