# BASH List Search Awk

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I'm very new to scripting and trying to work something out in bash. I have a data file filled with information that looks like this:

```
2   aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
4   aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1]   1 
8   aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
10  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
12  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaaa.aaa    11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
14  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
16  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaaa.aaa    11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
18  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
20  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaaa.aaa    11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
24  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaaa.aaa    11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
26  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaaa.aaa    11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
28  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
30  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1   
32  aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaaa.aaa    11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1
```

Where the *a's represent various letters and the 1's represent various numbers.

The lists are all supposed to go down vertically from 2 to 32 counting by 2's, however a lot of the lists are missing a couple components, such as the one I posted above which is missing 6 and 22. What I am trying to do is write a script that would go through and check to see if each number is there, and if not, add a line with the number at the front and nothing else trailing, so you'd have:

```
2   aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    
[1] 1   
4   aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1]   1 
6

8   aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aa11_1.aaa aaaa.aaa 11111   aaaa    1111    [1] 1      
...
```

From what I have read I believe the AWK function will be the most likely to succeed, however I'm not sure how to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: okay you have GOT to not use `*`'s and `.`'s as your data example, show what the actual data is (numbers, alphabet, whatever) using what you presented is going to yield aweful replies because both `.` and `*` are part of regular expression syntax.

Fix the problem and i will undo my -1 on your question

Comment: I think this seems like a perfect scenario to just read line by line and check to see if the line you are on starts with the number you expect. It would be the easiest way to insert that line and perhaps write it to some temporary file.

Comment: I'm very sorry that's my mistake. However I don't think I am allowed to post the actual data just based on privacy concerns. Would there be a better way I could represent them it using *'s? The periods are actually part of the data set so I don't think they need to be changed.

Comment: @tmanion That's what we have been doing so far, but there are a lot of these files and in order to speed up the process I have been tasked with trying to figure out a script to automate the process.

Comment: @ahmedmasud hope that is better!

Comment: You already asked this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191715/bash-first-element-in-list-recognition/24192214#comment37347972_24192214)

Comment: @user3735358 wouldn't be "nice" if you give feedback for all the solutions provide ?

Answer (score 1):

This awk is based on the output index range of 2-32 (by two) entries:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0} END {for(i=2;i<=32;i+=2) print (i in a ? a[i] : i)}' data
```

The breakdown:

- Store all the existing lines in an array by their index
- At the `END`, walk all known indexes (2-32) and either print the line, or the missing index

Comment: nice, but you need to store it in memory.

Comment: @klashxx - true, but that seems completely acceptable for at most 16 lines.

Comment: Awesome! The only problem is for some reason it got rid of the trailing data behind all of the numbers except the first one, and turned the initial 2 into a 32. Any ideas on how to fix those issues?

Comment: @user3735358 - it works fine for me, copying and pasting the data from the quesiton.  I'll make an edit that might help you, or it could be the format of the input file.

Comment: Yeah, there must have been something wrong with the format because it works perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
awk '{
        while( $1 > last_printed + 2) { 
            last_printed+=2; 
            print last_printed;
        }
        print;
        last_printed = $1;
     }' FILENAME
```

Comment: So this made something really weird happen where the terminal started showing large amounts of weird, constantly increasing numbers. Not really sure what was going on to be honest but something strange happened

Comment: Oops, sorry. I had the wrong condition in the while loop. I've fixed it, should work now.

Comment: For some reason this is only displaying the last line (32) of the list, any ideas?